# Update Symfony's form collection prototype through ajax

Tags: ajax, forms, symfony

I've built a form with Symfony, based on a Doctrine entity. The form contains form collections. Let's say the outer form is used to create a task. Many sub-tasks can be added to this task (the form collections part).

The task-form contains a choice field "category". De sub-task forms contain choice field "subcategory". The values of the subcategory field depend on the value chosen for the category field. To achieve this, I want to update the form prototype through AJAX when a main category has been chosen.

The JS-part of this is probably not that hard, so I'm sure I'd manage that. But I've got no idea what to do on the server/Symfony side to achieve this. Any hints in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: create a controller to list the values as `JSON`, then load the values via ajax and use a `Form Transformer` to make symfony accept the added value http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Comment: also this one might help https://www.adayinthelifeof.nl/2014/03/19/dynamic-form-modification-in-symfony2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a route that link to a new function(action) in the controller lets name it "ajaxGetSubCategoriesAction()"

implement it to get all the sub categories, then return them like this :

```
  //get the category id from ajax request 

  $categoryID = $request->request->get('category_id');

  //get all subcategories and return your result like this

  return new Response(json_encode($result));
```

then in the twig that renders the category put a data field inside the form tag or div tag like

this data-path you get it inside the JS file to know the path of the function you created to get the subcategories.
      $posturl = $formelement.data('path');
      var categoryid = //get it here with from your input field.
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $posturl,
            async: false,
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                category_id: categoryid
            }

```
    }).done(function (response) {
        inside response you will have all the subcategories returned from your ajaxGetSubCategories function
      }
```